# What questions belong on answers.ros and what belong in other places?

Tags: ros, gazebo, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen questions related to using ros with gazebo on answers.ros (and even asked a few myself too), but since answers.gazebosim.org has become active (and no longer has a wait period for questions to be approved), should `all` gazebo questions really be sent to that venue?

My personal feeling is that if it's a truly gazebo question then maybe, but if the question involves roslaunch, or how ROS parameters etc are set, then it should be a fair question here, but I'd like to know what the community thinks.

I'm guessing this would also apply to the many other projects that have interfaces with ROS, or using ROS with those projects as well...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47686/what-questions-belong-on-answers.ros-and-what-belong-in-other-places?/) by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2022 on 2012-11-07

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-11-07**:
This question was asked because I've seen some questions, that I thought were fair game here, sent elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would say, everything that does not pertain to gazebo itself is OK here.

E.g., if you want to know how to construct a roslaunch for gazebo that sets certain parameters in a certain way, you can ask that here, even if they are for gazebo, but if you want to know what parameter to set to make something work in gazebo, ask it at answers.gazebosim.org.

In other words, if you could replace gazebo by any other package for doing what you want, it is a ROS problem.

The reason for gazebo questions appearing here, might be that either they are old or people just didn't know that there is another spot or didn't remember to ask over there.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2012-11-07**:
On the subject of people not knowing there's another spot for certain questions (like gazebo or opencv), it might be helpful to have prominent links to answers.[gazebosim | opencv | etc].org.

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-11-07**:
Would this also apply to instructions that are hosted on the ros wiki that include the use of other projects?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-07**:
That depends on how much the project is tied into ROS. Some are specifically developed with ROS in mind and the authors will regularly check in here (e.g. hector_slam). Others are ROS wrappers for some library - in that case it might be advantageous to look for support at the project.